# Creating a binary search tree-linked list hybrid

Tags: java, data-structures, linked-list, binary-search-tree

I'm trying to write a structure that functions as a BST and also a linked list.

The idea is that the structure will be used as a tree when searching or inserting data, but printing all the data will use the structure as a list.

I've gotten my solution to work (i.e. an inorder traversal produces the same output as walking the list), unless you try to insert duplicate data. But I'm also wondering if there's a better way to do this, or even if it should be done!

Current implementation:

```
package com.practice.Structures;

public class BinarySearchListTree {
    TreeListNode root;
    TreeListNode head;
    public BinarySearchListTree() {
    }

    public void add(int data) {
        TreeListNode node = new TreeListNode(data);
        if(null == this.root) {
            this.root = node;
            this.head = node;
            return;
        }

        insertNode(node, this.root, this.root);
    }

    private void insertNode(TreeListNode node, TreeListNode parent, TreeListNode hold) {
       if(parent.getData() >= node.getData()) {
           if(null == parent.leftChild) {
               addLeftChild(node, parent, hold);
           } else {
               if(parent.leftChild.getData() >= hold.getData()) {
                   insertNode(node, parent.leftChild, hold);
               } else {
                   insertNode(node, parent.leftChild, parent.leftChild);
               }
           }
       } else {
           if(null == parent.rightChild) {
               addRightChild(node, parent);
           } else {
               insertNode(node, parent.rightChild, parent);
           }
       }
    }

    public void traverse() {
        inOrderTraverse(this.root);
        System.out.println();
    }

    public void printList() {
        printNode(this.head);
        System.out.println();
    }

    private void printNode(TreeListNode node) {
        if(null != node) {
            System.out.print(node.getData() + " ");
            printNode(node.next);
        }
    }

    private void inOrderTraverse(TreeListNode node) {
        if(node == null) {
            return;
        }
        inOrderTraverse(node.leftChild);
        System.out.print(node.getData() + " ");
        inOrderTraverse(node.rightChild);
    }

    private void addLeftChild(TreeListNode child, TreeListNode parent, TreeListNode hold) {
        parent.addLeftChild(child);
        child.next = parent;
        if(parent != hold) {
            hold.next = child;
        }
        if(parent == this.head) {
            this.head = child;
        }
    }

    private void addRightChild(TreeListNode child, TreeListNode parent) {
        parent.addRightChild(child);
        child.next = parent.next;
        parent.next = child;
    }
}
```

Comment: When printing the data, list-style, what requirements do you have on the order of printing?

Comment: Only that the list is ordered by the value of the node

Comment: Unless I misunderstood you, all you need to do then is to perform an inorder traversal of a normal BST.  No separate list is needed.

Comment: No, you're correct. It would be much easier, and not much slower, to just create a linked list from the inorder traversal if I needed the data as a list.

Comment: My real hope for this structure was to make inserting and searching a linked list much more efficient, but it seems like it'd be better to store it as a tree, and only return it as a list when needed

Comment: Absolutely, and I think it's very likely that you will never actually need the list as an actual linked list.  Lists are popular examples in intro computer science texts and course, but they are not in general very useful data structures.   This for lots of reasons, including the fact that as you've noticed they have poor search performance, and they also don't play nicely with CPU caches (which is important unless the objects in the list are huge).